US agencies phone numbers in the 1960s-1970s
For those who have a memory of it, I would like to understand the structure of the numbering plans and phone numbers of US agencies in the 1960s-1970s.
In an old congressional phonebook from 1971
I see entries like
Migratory Bird Conservation Commission
United States Department of the Interior Building
Phone, 343-4676 (Code 183, extension 4676)
CENTRAL INTELLIGENCE AGENCY
Washington, D.C. 20505, Phone, 351-1100 (Code 143)
DOMESTIC COUNCIL
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue 20500. Phone, 456-1414 (Code 145)
NATIONAL SECURITY COUNCIL
Old Executive Office Building, 20506. Phone, 395-3000 (Code 103, extension 3440)
I would like to understand what are the "Codes" that are mentioned on a lot of those entities.
What was the name of those codes and is there a comprehensive list somewhere ?
Was that tied to a specific network like the FTS (Federal Telecommunications System) ? how did you call a number ?
in the case of the DOMESTIC COUNCIL. Phone, 456-1414 (Code 145), was it 4561414145 + extension or something else ?

Perhaps a precursor to more modern area codes? I'm afraid, networks not under your control and historical trivia are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].
